# Distribution law in infinitary modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

This post is related to a question I originally asked on Philosophy Stack Exchange

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/100055/infinitary-modal-logic

In the modal logic (say, ${\bf K}$) the following theorems hold:

(1) $\Box (p\wedge q)\leftrightarrow(\Box p\wedge\Box q)$

(2) $(\Box p\vee\Box q)\rightarrow\Box (p\vee q)$

(3) $\Diamond (p\vee q)\leftrightarrow (\Diamond p\vee\Diamond q)$

(4) $\Diamond (p\wedge q)\rightarrow (\Diamond p\wedge\Diamond q)$

where $\Box$ and $\Diamond$ are the necessity and possibility operators, respectively.

Do these theorems hold in infinitary modal logic, i.e. do we have

(5) $\Box (\bigwedge_{n\in\omega} P_n)\leftrightarrow (\bigwedge_{n\in\omega}\Box p_n)$

(6) $(\bigvee_{n\in\omega}\Box p_n)\rightarrow(\Box\bigvee_{n\in\omega}p_n)$

(7) $\Diamond (\bigvee_{n\in\omega}p_n)\leftrightarrow(\bigvee_{n\in\omega}\Diamond p_n)$

(8) $\Diamond (\bigwedge_{n\in\omega}p_n)\rightarrow (\bigwedge_{n\in\omega}\Diamond p_n)$?

Comment: How do you *define* infinitary modal logic? FWIW, these formulas are obviously valid under the most straightforward Kripke semantics, if that is your definition.

Comment: Before claiming that a question is nonsense, or before maligning other sectors of the SE community, please remember the recent [updates to the SE code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). If the OP question is unclear or is a better fit for a different part of the network, use comments to indicate those issues.

Comment: @KristianBerry Since it's not clear after the question edit: the comments about "nonsense"  and "parrots" referred to the quote from an AI source (via your comment over on Philosophy.SE) which has since been removed from the question. The current question is not nonsense - though I don't think it meets the site's quality standards, due in part to not clarifying what it means for a sentence to hold in infinitary modal logic. And Emil was not calling any sector of the SE community parrots. Though that is a rather generous description of Bard...

Comment: @AlexKruckman my apologies, I thought the reference to parrots was to the PhilSE. Is it possible to move this question to the MathSE instead?

Comment: It looks like it was a mistake to remove the chatbot comment. I only wanted to recenter the question on the validity of schemes (5) to (8). Perhaps I should delete the question altogether and start afresh on MSE.

Comment: To avoid potential misinterpretation, I deleted the "parrot" comment, as it is no longer relevant after the edit. Removing the chatbot quote improved the question, and it was the right thing to do. I agree the question would be more suitable for math.SE than here, though.

Comment: I also deleted my comment about nonsense, as it's no longer relevant.